# How it is possible to avoid a push in Github when the workflow tests fails?

Tags: python, github, testing, github-actions

I create the workflow to test my Python application before commit. The problem is that if the tests fail, the commit is pushed anyways. How I could add a condition to avoid the push if the test don't succeed?

Structure of the workflow file .yml here below.

```yaml
name: Python application
on:
  push:
      branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.8
      uses: actions/setup-python@v1
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        pip install flake8
        # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
        flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
        # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
        flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pip install pytest
        pytest
```

[Test fail screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEeP5.png)

Comment: That workflow (*any* workflow, for that matter) can only *get* the code if it's been pushed. If you want to test *before* pushing, you need to do so *locally*. You could look into git hooks to automate that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't actually prevent the push with a CI system, for a couple of reasons.

First, your CI system needs to have access to the data to push, which means it must live in a repository somewhere so it can be fetched.  Second, CI systems can take a long time to run, and nobody wants to hang around and wait for their push to either succeed or fail while their CI system runs.  What if you pushed right before the end of your workday?

The way you typically do this is to push to a branch, let the CI system run, and then merge it.  If you're working with multiple people, then using pull requests and setting your CI to run whenever one is opened or updated is the right move.  Otherwise, you can just set up your workflow to operate on all branches (like so) and then merge the branch when it passes:

```
on: push
```